# Java, Cannot invoke "String.hashCode()" because "<local3>" is null

Tags: java

i'm implementing a dashboard with different kind of users (i'm using Cognito). So, if a user gets signed in, he has to login using the temporary password. When that happens, the user resets the password and, with a switch case, my program understands what user group he is in, so that can open the according window (Admins, Cooks excetera have different dashboards).

But, after the 'change password' button gets clicked, this it the problem it gives me:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.hashCode()" because "<local3>" is null
    at com.example.ratatouille23/com.example.ratatouille23.Controller.Login.ReimpostaPasswordController.onBtnConfermaNuovaPasswordClicked(ReimpostaPasswordController.java:35)
```

Line 35 is where the switch case starts.

This is my code:

```
public void onBtnConfermaNuovaPasswordClicked(String oldPassword, String newPassword) {
        try {
            if (verificaPasswordUguali(oldPassword, newPassword)) {
                Utente.ReimpostaPasswordPrimoAccesso(newPassword);
                switch (Utente.getGroup()) {
                    case "Amministratori":
                        FXMLLoader loaderAdmin = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/homepage-admin.fxml"));
                        scene = new Scene(loaderAdmin.load());
                        Main.getPrimaryStage().close();
                        stage = new Stage();
                        Main.setPrimaryStage(stage);
                        stage.setTitle("Ratatouille23");
                        stage.close();
                        stage.setScene(scene);
                        stage.show();
                        break;
                    case "Supervisori":
                        FXMLLoader loaderSuperv = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/homepage-supervisore.fxml"));
                        scene = new Scene(loaderSuperv.load());
                        Main.getPrimaryStage().close();
                        stage = new Stage();
                        Main.setPrimaryStage(stage);
                        stage.setTitle("Ratatouille23");
                        stage.close();
                        stage.setScene(scene);
                        stage.show();
                        break;
                    case "Addetti_Alla_Cucina":
                        FXMLLoader loaderCucina = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/homepage-cucina.fxml"));
                        scene = new Scene(loaderCucina.load());
                        Main.getPrimaryStage().close();
                        stage = new Stage();
                        Main.setPrimaryStage(stage);
                        stage.setTitle("Ratatouille23");
                        stage.close();
                        stage.setScene(scene);
                        stage.show();
                        break;
                    case "Addetti_Alla_Sala":
                        FXMLLoader loaderSala = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/homepage-sala.fxml"));
                        scene = new Scene(loaderSala.load());
                        Main.getPrimaryStage().close();
                        stage = new Stage();
                        Main.setPrimaryStage(stage);
                        stage.setTitle("Ratatouille23");
                        stage.close();
                        stage.setScene(scene);
                        stage.show();
                        break;
                }
            } else {
                    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
                    alert.setTitle("Password errata");
                    alert.setHeaderText("Errore nell'inserimento delle password.");
                    Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
                    if (result.get() == ButtonType.OK) {
                        //
                    }
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (
                CognitoIdentityProviderException e) {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
            alert.setTitle("Conferma");
            alert.setHeaderText(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
            if (result.get() == ButtonType.OK) {
                //
            }
        }
    }
```

The fact is that the password actually GETS resetted, so the problem is actually only in the switch case and i don't know how to deal with this.

Comment: So, which is line 35 in your code?

Comment: It's the switch case, sorry, i forgot to mention it

Comment: `Utente.getGroup()` returns `null`, switch on string doesn't support `null` in Java 20 and older, and since Java 21 only supports `null` if there is an explicit `case null`